# как создать страницу в которой данные будут постоянно меняться

Tags: php, база-данных, redbeanphp, link

Этот код работает отлично, он выводит все продукты. Первый цыкл для того чтобы выводилась столько продуктов сколько прсутствует в таблице, а второй для того чтобы данные выводились поочерёдно. Теперь этот код выводит все продукты и в конце кода где есть ссылка <<больше>> при нажатии отправляет на страницу product.php но нужно сделать так чтобы в этой странице отображались данные того продукта на которую нажали. Если нажали на <<ручку>> то на product.php должна отображаться описание ручки, а если нажали на <<книгу>> то описание книги. Описание продуктов есть в базе данных   $r['description']

```php
$length = R::count('products');
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "magnete");
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `products`");

for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<div class="product">';
        echo "<img src='".$r['image']."'>";
        echo "<h2>";
        echo $r['name'];
        echo "</h2>";
        echo "<p>";
        echo $r['price'];
        echo "</p>";
        echo '<a target="_blank" href="';
        echo $r['from'];
        echo '">на сайт</a>';
        echo "<a href='product.php?id='".$r['id']."''>больше</a>";
        echo "</div>";      
    }
}
```

Последняя ссылка в div-е правильная?

Надеюсь не слишком непонятно сформулировал вопрос.

Comment: Не совсем понятна суть. Во-первых зачем Вы загоняете цикл в цикл? Для каждого продукта Вы выводите все продукты из БД. И давайте поподробнее что хотите сделать. Создать страницу, на которой будут кнопки или ссылки с названием продуктов, верно? При нажатии на которые будут выводиться данные этого продукта в из БД как в примере(картинка, название и т.п)?

Comment: Нет этот код работает отлично, он выводит все продукты. Первый цыкл для того чтобы выводилась столько продуктов сколько прсутствует в таблице, а второй для того чтобы данные выводились поочерёдно. Теперь этот код выводит все продукты  и в конце кода где есть ссылка <<больше>> при нажатии отправляет на страницу но нужно делать так чтобы  в этой странице отображались данные того продукта на которую нажали. Если нажали на <<ручку>> то на product.php должна отображаться описание ручки, а если нажали на <<книгу>> то описание книги которая есть в базе данных

Comment: Вы не правы. Вы получаете количество записей в БД $length = R::count('products'); Дальше через функцию for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) { ОТ нуля ДО количества продуктов - вы выводите функцию while, которая сама по себе выполняет действие для каждого значения $result  ряд результата запроса в качестве ассоциативного массива. Почитайте документацию, как делать это правильно.

Comment: Да точно. Просто раньше он был нужен, а потом код изменился и for болььше не нужен

Answer (score 1):

Просто уже нужен на страницу product.php проверит если есть $_GET['id'] тогда делает запрос на базу данных и получит все информацию что связанно на ид продукта

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])&& $_GET['id']!=null){
$id = $_GET['id'];
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "magnete");
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE id='$id'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo $row['name']
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Переходя по ссылке id не заполняется 
вид url такой http://localhost/product.php?id=    а так ваш код работает. Не подскажете почему id не заполняется? Ошибка в последнем теге <a> да?

Comment: Зачем там фор цикл? там без фор цикла будет работат без проблем

Comment: @DVD_AM Жора Хэмалян всё правильно Вам написал. Предполагается наличие имени name="id" в разметке html. Пример - <button name='id' id='id'>КатегорияПродукта#1</button>

Comment: Мне просто нужно чтобы при нажатии на ссылку в мето $r['id'] стояла id конкретного продукта. Знаю что ответ Жоры Хзмалян правильная

Answer (score 0):

В последнем теге  есть апечатка которая не будет выводиться компилятором.
Присутствуют некотрые лишние кавычки, 
должен быть так:

```php
    echo "<a href='product.php?id=".$r['id']."'>больше</a>";
```

а код для product.php должен быть таким:

```php
    $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'magnete');

    if($_GET['id']!=null){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $idresult = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE id='$id'");
        while($ri = mysqli_fetch_assoc($idresult)){
            echo '<div class="product">';
            echo "<img src='".$r['image']."'>";
            echo "<h2>";
            echo $r['name'];
            echo "</h2>";
            echo "<p>";
            echo $r['price'];
            echo "</p>";
            echo '<a target="_blank" href="';
            echo $r['from'];
            echo '">на сайт</a>';
            echo "<a href='product.php?id=".$r['id']."'>больше</a>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
```

В других аставленных ответах тоже были апечатки